# getting the Translation Error Class not found when tryin gto generate random variable

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Math.Random.Examples.GenerateRandomNumbers.html) to generate a random function of time:

```
model testData

  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;

  parameter Real k = 1.0;
  Real theta1;
  Real theta2;
  parameter Real tau = 1.0;
  
  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Period samplePeriod = 0.05;
  parameter Integer globalSeed = 30020;
  output Real omega1;
  
algorithm
  when initial() then
    state1024 := Generators.Xorshift1024star.initialState(localSeed, globalSeed);
    omega1     := 0;
  elsewhen sample(0,samplePeriod) then
    (omega1,state1024) := Generators.Xorshift1024star.random(pre(state1024));
  end when;
  
public
  parameter Integer id = Utilities.initializeImpureRandom(globalSeed);
  discrete Real rImpure;
  Integer iImpure;
algorithm
  when initial() then
    rImpure := 0;
    iImpure := 0;
  elsewhen sample(0,samplePeriod) then
    rImpure := Utilities.impureRandom(id=id);
    iImpure := Utilities.impureRandomInteger(
          id=id,
          imin=-1234,
          imax=2345);
  end when;

initial equation
  theta1 = 0;
  theta2 = 0;
  der(theta2) = 0;

equation
  der(theta1) = omega1;
  der(der(theta2)) = tau + k * (theta1 - theta2);

annotation(experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 10, Tolerance = 1e-6, Interval = 0.02));

end testData;
```

however, I get the error message:

> Translation Error
>
> Class Utilities.initializeImpureRandom not found in scope testData (looking for a function or record).
>
> Translation Error
>
> Error occurred while flattening model testData

I would appreciate if you could help me understand what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing some imports, see below, some variable declarations and you were using der(der(...)) which doesn't work, you need to bind the internal der to a variable. This model below compiles and simulates (I don't know if the results are fine or not).

```
model testData

  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  import Modelica.Math.Random.Generators;
  import Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities;

  parameter Real k = 1.0;
  Real theta1;
  Real theta2;
  Real der_theta2;
  parameter Real tau = 1.0;

  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Period samplePeriod = 0.05;
  parameter Integer globalSeed = 30020;
  parameter Integer localSeed = 614657;
  output Real omega1;
  discrete Integer state1024[33](each start=0, each fixed = true);

algorithm
  when initial() then
    state1024 := Generators.Xorshift1024star.initialState(localSeed, globalSeed);
    omega1     := 0;
  elsewhen sample(0,samplePeriod) then
    (omega1,state1024) := Generators.Xorshift1024star.random(pre(state1024));
  end when;

public
  parameter Integer id = Utilities.initializeImpureRandom(globalSeed);
  discrete Real rImpure;
  Integer iImpure;
algorithm
  when initial() then
    rImpure := 0;
    iImpure := 0;
  elsewhen sample(0,samplePeriod) then
    rImpure := Utilities.impureRandom(id=id);
    iImpure := Utilities.impureRandomInteger(
          id=id,
          imin=-1234,
          imax=2345);
  end when;

initial equation
  theta1 = 0;
  theta2 = 0;
  der(theta2) = 0;
  der_theta2 = 0;

equation
  der(theta1) = omega1;
  der(theta2) = der_theta2;
  der(der_theta2) = tau + k * (theta1 - theta2);

annotation(experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 10, Tolerance = 1e-6, Interval = 0.02));

end testData;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. @marco had answered first. So I was ethically obliged to accept his answer. But you also have my love ❤️ and respect 

Comment: No, Adrian was faster. But I still posted my answer, due to additional information.

Comment: Oh. I'm really sorry then. I will change it.

Comment: posted a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57886368/4999991). would really appreciate if you could help me with that too.

Answer (score 3):

The example `Modelica.Math.Random.Examples.GenerateRandomNumbers` uses relative class paths.

`Utilities.initializeImpureRandom` for example points to `Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities.initializeImpureRandom`, which works due to the package hierarchy

```
Modelica
|- Math
   |- Random
      |- Examples
      |- Utilities
```

If you copy the code of the example to a different location, the relative paths will not work anymore.

Dymola updates relative paths when models are duplicated (via New > Duplicate Class). Openmodelica apparently not.

Just add the following two imports to the top of your code and the class paths will work:

```
import Modelica.Math.Random.Generators;
import Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities;
```

But your model contains additonal errors:

- The declaration of the variables `localSeed` and `state1024` is missing. Just copy them from the original example
- `der(der(theta2))` is not supported. Create an intermediate variable `der_theta2 = der(theta2)`