# filtering a harmonic disturbance introduced by a complaint element

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing

**TL;DR** I want to find `theta_1` in the system below from `theta_2`, without knowing other parameters.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57886368/4999991), I have modeled the system below

in Modelica language and solved by OpenModelica generating a CSV file:

```
"time", "theta1", "theta2"
     0,        0,        0
  0.02, -6.40192, -7.79226
  0.04, -12.8038, -12.1422
  0.06, -19.2058, -18.1304
  0.08, -25.6077, -26.7809
```

You may find the Modelica code and CSV [here in this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/aeffc3275760d5785cfe2d821a3c7707). What I want to do is to filter the `theta_2` to get `theta_1` without knowing the sample rates for `tau` and `theta_1`, compliant element `k` and angular inertia `J`. I speculate that the rotational spring would leave a distinguishable footprint in the frequency domain spectrum of the angle data `theta_2`.

what I have done so far:

1. Importing the data as a Pandas data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("exportedVariables.csv")
df.head()
```

2. plotting the data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df["time"], df["theta2"], df["time"], df["theta1"])
plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
plt.ylabel("Angle (deg)")
```

3. calculating the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of `theta_2` data:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft

theta2_scipy_fft = fft(df["theta2"])

N = len(df.index)
time = df["time"].values
dt = np.mean(np.diff(time))

frequency = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * dt), N // 2)

plt.plot(frequency, 2.0 / N * np.abs(theta2_scipy_fft[0: N // 2]))
plt.xscale("log")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude (dB)")
```

However, what I see here is the first two dominant amplitudes in the spectrogram are actually the sample rate by which the random value of `tau` and `omega_1` are generated and I can't find the pick I was looking for. So I don't know how to go forward from here. I would appreciate if you could help me know if it is possible to filter out the disturbance caused by the rotational spring without knowing the system and how it can be implemented.